# Using Google Drive to manage large volume of documents

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, google-docs-api

I have a CMS database (SQL Server) that stores around 2 million documents PDF, Word, Excel etc. averaging 2MB in size.

I want to move these docs and upload them into Google Drive, get an Id back, and store this as a reference in SQL Server.

Has anyone done this or knows of possible problems with this approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it directly via SQL Server, but you can write a simple .NET (or other) app that does what you're after.

Here is the [drive API documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/), [API clients](https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads), and specific instructions for [uploading files](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-uploads).

Kyle

Comment: Apologies for the late response.  The API clients link (https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/drive/v2/) was exactly what I was after - cheers.